# RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported

Tags: pytorch, jupyter

When running my VAE in a jupyter notebook, I get this CUDA device-side assert error. It started appearing after changing my loss function, but after reverting all changes, I still get it.

```
for e in range(epochs):
            print('EPOCH: ',e)
            kl_factor=self.kl_factor
            for t, (x,y) in enumerate(self.train):
                self.model.train()  # put model to training mode
                x = x.to(device=self.device, dtype=self.dtype)  # move to device, e.g. GPU
                y = y.to(device=self.device, dtype=self.dtype) 

                scores, kl = self.model(x)
                loss = self.lossfn(scores,y)
                mse_losses.append(loss.detach().cpu().numpy())
                loss += kl * kl_factor
                kl_losses.append((kl * kl_factor).detach().cpu().numpy())
                total_losses.append(loss.detach().cpu().numpy())

                kl_factor = np.minimum(self.kl_max,kl_factor*(self.kl_rate))

                # Zero out all of the gradients for the variables which the optimizer
                # will update.
                self.optim.zero_grad()

                # This is the backwards pass: compute the gradient of the loss with
                # respect to each  parameter of the model.
                loss.backward()

                # Actually update the parameters of the model using the gradients
                # computed by the backwards pass.
                self.optim.step()
```

It occurs at self.optim.step

lossfn is MSELoss, Adam Optimizer

Setting device to cpu does nothing, but weirdly exporting it to a new .py file works fine. CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1 using os also does nothing

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace and indicate which line is throwing the error?